# Issues adding Ubuntu 14.04 to Windows Server 2012 AD domain

Tags: samba, active-directory

I am trying to join an Ubuntu 14.04 host to a windows active directory (Windows Server 2012) - using native tools

I've used [this](http://blogging.dragon.org.uk/join-ubuntu1404-t0-samba-winbind/) as a guide. I've tried a few variations in configs, e.g. toggling `dns_lookup_realm` and `dns_lookup_kdc` on and off. I initially had some issues with `resolveconf` but I uninstalled it and after updating network setting I could resolve `srv` settings for _ldap and _krb records as expected. I am able to `kinit` and get a ticket issued, and had a successful `net ads join`. `wbinfo` run with `-u`, `-g` and returns gids for `-r someuser`, but `-i someuser` returns:

```
failed to call wbcGetpwnam: WBC_ERR_DOMAIN_NOT_FOUND
Could not get info for user someuser
```

I am unable to authenticate as users either, e.g. if ssh'ing or via console login - user not found in passwd. This is my `nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:         compat winbind
group:          compat winbind
shadow:         compat winbind
```

`getent group` only returns local groups after a long delay (as if it's contacting the PDC, but not getting any response). `getent group "domain admins"` and `domain_admins` don't return anything.

So I think I am pretty close to getting a domain logon on the host, but not sure what is wrong. Anything obvious wrong in my setup? How I can debug this issue to get domain logons working properly?

Answer (score 0):

after 4 days of battling with various settings to get winbind to work, I found this: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html

5 minutes and the host was logging onto the domain.